# Can I serve up a content-length from an Xpage Rest Service

Tags: json, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have written a JSON Rest Service in an Xpage. Works fine. Our outside programmer is going to consume it on the iSeries using RPG.

We have successfully consumed a handful of rest services on the 400 using exactly similar services.

The outside programmer wants use to send a "content-length" header. I cannot find any parameter in the design element to add this. Maybe it is not possible.

Comment: Why do you not add it programmatically?

Comment: Is it time to replace the "Outside programmer" with a capable java programmer.  Typical use of content-length show a download progress bar.  Validating with content-length is a bad practice.  A checksum  or digital signature is the standard way to validate a download.

Comment: Since we are using JSON can't he just validate by searching for the end of the JSON? I am curious, why is validating with a checksum a bad practice?

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate the excuses that you'll receive from the "Outside Programmer"  This is simple rpg calls java to consume webservice.  java stores webservice response in qtemp.  rpg reads qtemp file.  It's done this way.

Comment: validating with a checksum is cpu intensive go for it if its in your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

`content-length` is a header that belongs to the underlying response object. So you have to use the [ExternalContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getResponse()) to get the [Response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) where you use the `setHeader(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)` method to set content-length.

This works in all flavours, you need to capture the response in the "before render response" event.

When you opt to write a [custom service](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-9Q55QL?Open) using the service bean, then it is a little easier, since the response object is handed over as a parameter.

Let us know how it goes!